# Laravel Elixir with JQuery and JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, webpack, laravel-elixir

I'm unable to get JQuery UI required when using Laravel Elixir with Webpack.

Here is my gulpfile.js, nothing unusual:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir.config.sourcemaps = false;

elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('app.js');
});
```

My app.js file is where I'm trying to require both JQuery and JQuery UI. I've tried multiple things but this is where I'm at:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = $.extend(require('jquery-ui'));
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get JQuery UI required and working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out.  jquery-ui, as is built and in `npm` doesn't contain a dist file.  In order to solve this you have to use a file called `jquery-ui-bundle`.  Run the following command `npm i -S jquery-ui-bundle`.

Then require it after jquery

```
require('jquery');
require('jquery-ui-bundle');
```

Hope this saves someone some time, I spent a few hours figuring that out!

Comment: @JagadeshaNH  are you using elixir for that too?

Comment: where do you put the require??

Comment: @Rabb-bit to import the modules

Comment: Thanks @JakeSylvestre. This saved me a lot of time!!

Answer (score 3):

`npm install jquery-ui-bundle --save`

In your bootstrap.js add this:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = $.extend(require('jquery-ui-bundle'));
```

`npm run dev`

Answer (score 1):

Three simple steps:

1. Install npm package: `npm i -S jquery-ui-bundle`
2. Import javascript (somewhere after jquery importing): `require('jquery-ui-bundle');`
3. Import css styles: `node_modules/jquery-ui-bundle/jquery-ui.css`